# php how to fit a text into a box

Tags: php, text, fonts, truetype

I have the bounds of a rectangular box. 
Is it possible to fit a text (with custom font) into the box while not knowing the text size. 
I mean, is there a php function which sets the proper text size so that the text is fitted into the user-defined box?
I do not need text wrapping.

The only functions I found are [imagettfbbox](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php) and  [imagettftext](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php).

imagettfbbox does exactly the opposite(gives the bounds, provided a font size) while imagettftext is used to write text on an image, only if fontSize is known.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using php gd?  If so, then I would use `imagettfbbox`.  Just define all the parameters except size.  Then outside of that loop on size until it is small enough to fit in your defined space.  I've done this before.  It doesn't do any actual image creative in memory, so it's very fast (much faster than actually creating the image).

```
for($size=40;$size>5;$size--){
  $sizearray=imagettfbbox ( $size , 0- , 'font.ttf' , $message );
    $width=$sizearray[0] + $sizearray[4];
    if($width<$threshold/*you define*/){
      //you've got your $size
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought of that but assumed performance would take a hit.. good to know thats not the case.. thanks! will try that out!

Comment: you could adjust the constants in the for loop if you have a good guess of the range. you could count up instead of down.  you could also increment/decrement by more than one if your width is way off of the threshold.  all of these are ideas of your worried about performance.  you can time it too and i bet this loop takes significantly less time than your actual image work/generation/export/etc